# AngularUI show popover manually from condition in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form that have an email field. This form have a submit button. When the user clicks the submit button then I would like to show a popover above the email field. And I can't get it to work. I have trie the following.

```
// Obviously doesn't work...
<input type="text" ng-model="email" popover={{submitMessage}} popover-trigger="[want to trigger it automatically]" placeholder="E-mail"></input>
```

My controller content looks something like this:

```
if (!validationService.isEmailValid($scope.email)) {
    $scope.submitMessage = 'Invalid e-mail';

    // Now I would like to display my submitMessage above my textfield...
```

Does anyone know if that's possible. If so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!validationService.isEmailValid($scope.email)) {
    $scope.submitMessage = 'Invalid e-mail';
     **$scope.$apply();**
```

Comment: Thanks, now the popover is shown with the right content. But I would like to trigger it (show) as well (not only on focus). Is that possible? Updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: add a button for the right side. If you click the button, then shown the message on a new popup. that's it. Please  start this new task to a new question.

Comment: But it's not a popup, it's a angularUI bootstrap popover.